# Error :illegal start of expression and ";" expected

Tags: java, error-handling, expression

Question:when dog's is barking and when it's before 8am or 22pm, return true, otherwise return false.

My code:

```
public class Barkingdog {

    public boolean bark(boolean barking, int hourofDay) {
        if (barking) {
            if (hourofDay >= 0 && hourofDay <= 8) {
                return true;
            } else if (hourofDay >= 22 && hourofDay < 24) {
            return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to test my code:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static boolean main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        System.out.println(public boolean bark (true, 4););
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use `System.out.println(bark(true, 4));`

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of `Barkingdog` and call your `bark` method from it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Barkingdog dog = new Barkingdog();
    System.out.println(dog.bark(true, 4));
}
```

Also, please use proper Java naming conventions. Classes should use camel casing:

```
public class BarkingDog { ... }
```

You could also simply the logic of your `bark` method:

```
public boolean bark(boolean barking, int hourOfDay) {
    boolean morning = hourOfDay >= 0 && hourOfDay <= 8;
    boolean night = hourOfDay >= 22 && hourOfDay < 24;

    return barking && morning || night;
}
```

And `bark` doesn't seem to be a proper name for this behavior.

`boolean barking` represents whether the dog is actually barking, and since `barking` could be `false`, calling `dog.bark(false, 8)` could cause confusion: we are telling the dog to perform the behavior `bark`, but the dog is not barking (specified by the `false` argument).

May wanna choose a more descriptive name for the behavior, such as `isBarkingUnderirably`, where we are checking whether the `barking` is occuring at a desirable time or not.

Answer (score -1):

1. Please make sure that your main() method has correct signature.
2. You are making a call to the method and hence do not need to provide the access modifier. You specify access modifier only while declaring.
3. Remove the additional `;` while calling.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   // write your code here
     System.out.println(bark(true, 4));
   }
   ```

Comment: This won't work - you're calling an instance method from a static context.